# ASP.NET MVC SelectList extension method not selecting list item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

Coming from a long line of VB.NET (blech) I kind of skipped over the concept of extension methods when I started C#'ing about 5 years ago. These things are great. My first attempt, however, is a failure. I'm trying to create a simple extension method for SelectList that selects the only item in the list whenever there is 1 SelectListItem.

The below does not work:

```
public static SelectList SelectIfOnlyOneItem(this SelectList list)
{
   if (list.Count() == 1) { list.Single().Selected = true; }
   return list;
}

FooList = new SelectList(new[] { "Only Item" }, "").SelectIfOnlyOneItem();
```

but

```
FooList = new SelectList(new[] { "Only Item" }, "Only Item");
```

works fine.

Comment: What if you don't pass in the 2nd parameter to the constructor?

Comment: @itsme86 Same thing

Comment: Curious what the debugger shows for `FooList.SelectedValue` after the call.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try `... list.Items[0].Selected = true; ...`

Comment: @itsme86 SelectedValue is an empty string

Comment: @nurchi list.Items is IEnumerable so can't use array style indexing

Comment: What is the point of this? Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored if you binding to a model property so its not clear what your trying to achieve.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes that is correct but this is for when coming to a page for the first time and no model property has been set yet. The extension method defined in the answer below auto selects the only item in the list if exists.

Comment: @kcabrams, thanks for clarification, I didn't have a compiler handy to try it. Well, how about `list.Items.Single().Selected = true;`

Comment: @kcabrams, in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456049/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-extension-method-not-selecting-list-item?noredirect=1#comment85986214_49456049) from yesterday, the answer below selects a brand new list, is this desirable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should work for you:

```
public static SelectList SelectIfOnlyOneItem(this SelectList list)
{
   if (list.Count() == 1) 
   { 
       list= new SelectList(list.ToList(), "Value", "Text", list.Single().Value)
   }

   return list;
}
```

I've noticed through my own trials that when setting the `Selected` property on a `SelectListItem` that this property will not always translate to the `SelectList` container for the items. If anyone has more detailed information on why this is, I'd love to hear it. I've done a bit of experimentation with this and have so far been unable to find out why this occurs.

In the past, I've overcome this by using the `new SelectList` overload that allows you to explicitly specify the selected value.

Comment: Almost! I had to change it to this `list = new SelectList(list.ToList(), "Value", "Text", list.Single().Value);`